# Select list with javascript in the apex oracle

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, return-value, selectlistitem

I use javascript for select list let's call it max_mode item. with logical terms like this, for counter redeem = 1 and 3,

```
$('#P223_MAX_MODE').find('option').remove().end(); 
$("#P223_MAX_MODE").append('<option value=4>Program</option>');
```

and for false conditions,

```
$('#P223_MAX_MODE').find('option').remove().end();
$("#P223_MAX_MODE").append('<option value=2>Day</option>');
$("#P223_MAX_MODE").append('<option value=3>Month</option>');
$("#P223_MAX_MODE").append('<option value=8>Week</option>');
$("#P223_MAX_MODE").append('<option value=9>Year</option>');
```

this process and conditions are running well, but when the update select list was changed not according to the initial conditions. In the dynamic action settings in true and false conditions, I change the **fire on Initialization to 'yes'**. and the javacsript was active in an updated state. *but the problem is, the stored return value data is not called when updating*. How can I solve this ?

[image]

[image]
[image: when Initialization is set to 'no', return value is active. but the dynamic javascript action is not called]
[image: when Initialization is set to 'yes', return value is not active. but dynamic javascript actions can be called]

Comment: can you write the condition and what type of condition are you using? please add screenshots to make easier for understanding

Comment: What triggers this process? If it's a button then set up the 'Behavior' action to submit page. Or set up the 'Items to submit' field inside the action so you have to select all the items that you want to use.

Comment: @mohamadsubhibouchi okay, I've added the screenshots, hopefully it will make it easier for you

Comment: @Tivi so what triggers this action is dynamic action on change based on item counter redeem. when the create process runs smoothly as you wish, but the update display process does not. you have to set the fire on Initialization to 'yes' first, then the js script was called in the update process. but a new problem arises in the item max mode return value is not working

Comment: screenshots 1 select list max mode, when Fire on Initializationis set to no, return value is active.
but the dynamic javascript action is not called.

screenshots 2 select list max mode, when Fire on Initializationis set to yes, return value is not active.
but dynamic javascript actions can be called

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the Item Value when you change it, you can use Javascript or PLSQL Dynamic action to submit

Comment: in the source section? I have filled the source with the database column item